# Named Elliptical Curve parameters

Tags: elliptic-curves

Are named curve parameters always the same? I know this may be a stupid question however I think this is the case. For example the secp256r1 is defined in this documet http://www.secg.org/SEC2-Ver-1.0.pdf.

Comment: https://gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gcrypt/ECC-key-parameters.html seems this is the case.

Comment: Yes, fixing a set of parameters is exactly the point of standardizing a named curve.

Answer (score 1):

They are *de facto* conventions that somewhere may not being followed. I think the one you mention has started with the [P1363](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/1363/), but not sure if there is something previous.

It is the first thing one have to check in any document: which is the naming convention followed there. Perhaps also is useful to see from there some of them comes. The [Weierstrass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Weierstrass) Normal Form (or [WNF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve#Elliptic_curves_over_the_real_numbers)) can be saw as:

$y^{2} + a_{1}xy + a_{3}y = x^{3} + a_{2}x^{2} + a_{4}x + a_{6}$

And usually uses it reduced form when is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ as:

$ y^{2} = x^{3} + ax + b $

On characteristic 2 ($\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$), I think is more usual the form:

$ y^{2} + xy = x^{3} + ax^{2} + b $

Different names for the same parameters and even mixing them. Not forgetting that there are many more curve representations, one each you can find even different conventions.

Then points naming can change from one document to another, where is usual to see $G$ as the generator (also represented as $<G>$), but cannot be assumed because you can see a $P$ or $Q$ or $R$.

I think coherence is important and where ever it's used, the convention must be described at the beginning and followed to the end. This convention you mention, perhaps is the more spread.

Answer (score 1):

Usually named curves are unique. That's kind of the point of named curves; the curve gets assigned a specific identifier to a curve and API's use that too look up the stored curves instead of explictly parameterizing the values. Strings however aren't registered anywhere. So it may happen that curves get assigned the same identifier. For the well known curves it is of course very unlikely that there will ever be an overlap as the developers of the API's will not allow another curve with the same name.

This kind of confusion can be avoided by assigning a curve an OID (object identifier). OID's are basically a path in a tree leading up to a leaf node where each node has a name and a unique number. The first numbers are assigned to national organizations by ISO, which then create their own tree. After a few nodes a specific company or organization is identified. It is then responsible for their own branch. For instance your secp256r1 curve is assigned the OID: [{iso(1) member-body(2) us(840) ansi-x962(10045) curves(3) prime(1) prime256v1(7)} or 1.2.840.10045.3.1.7 for short](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.3.1.7). Many API's also allow selection by this unique OID, so a developer can be sure he gets the right curve.

Named curves have the advantage that the user can be reasonably sure that the curve parameters are actually safe to use. In that case the curve must of course be correctly identified. This is why e.g. PKIX (the standards that are used for X5.09 certificates in e.g. HTTPS/SSL/TLS) [requires the use of named certificates identified by an OID](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480#section-2.1.1).

Comment: What do you think, should I also add something about naming conventions? What about the use of OID's in PKIX certificates?